# Активная кнопка html5

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Как добавить стиль к неактивной/активной кнопки?

Вот что я имею ввиду

```html
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Сделать проверку чтобы при заполнении текстового поля, кнопка активировалась и наоборот.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var text = document.getElementById('input-text');
var button = document.getElementById('input-button');

text.addEventListener('input', handle);
text.addEventListener('keyup', handle);

function handle(e) {
  if (text.value.length >= 5) {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
    if (text.value.length <= 5) {
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="input-text" type="text">
<input id="input-button" type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```